Firebase push notifications delivered inconsistently on Android
We are building an ionic application using Firebase FCM for our push notifications via the Pigeon elixir library. We have noticed that some of out Android notifications don't get received by our android devices, even though we receive a successful response from Firebase while all of our IOS notifications are received perfectly.
We are sending the following message payload:
{
  "message": {
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Test title",
      "body": "Test message"
    },
    "data": {
      "notification_id": "123"
    },
    "apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "badge" : 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


We'd expect to receive all of the notifications on Android but some never get received on the device. Does anyone know if there is a solution for this with any parameters or has anyone experienced this before?

Try setting the priority specifically for android in message payload like this
"android":{
"priority":"normal"
},
Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#:~:text=Data%20messages%2C%20by%20contrast%2C%20contain,enforces%20a%201000%20character%20limit.

Try setting the priority specifically for android in message payload like this
"android":{ "priority":"normal" },

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#:~:text=Data%20messages%2C%20by%20contrast%2C%20contain,enforces%20a%201000%20character%20limit.
